# creating a Python script with a recursive function to display the sum of the first n integers, where n is entered by the user

Tags: python

what is wrong with this code(newbie)

```
def find_sum (n):
    sum_num = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
    n=int(input ("Enter a number: "))
    return sum_num
print("The sum of first"+sum_num)
```

Comment: `sum_num` is a local variable. Can't be call outside the function. also you didn't call the `find_sum`

Comment: This isn't recursive

Comment: A few things are wrong; you never call `find_sum` and you don't ask for `n` until you already need it

Comment: If you're trying to do this with recursion, you would be calling `find_sum` in itself. I think it would be helpful to include an example of the output you're expecting as well.

Comment: You defined n as a parameter to the function I don't think you can than ask it as input. Moreover you are using n before you ask it as input. Try asking n outside the function and passing it to find_sum as an actual parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python takes code one step at a time so you cant define n after you used it you have to define it before using n and if you want to get the return value you will use the difined function as shown below:

```
n=int(input ("Enter a number: "))
def find_sum (n):
    sum_num = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
    return sum_num
print("The sum of first" ,find_sum(n))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really need a *recursive* function, then it'll be something like this:

```
def recursive_sum(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n + recursive_sum(n - 1)

print(recursive_sum(10))  # -> 55
```

But are you actually sure it has to be recursive?

Comment: else is unnecessary since you return if the statement is true

Comment: True, but is the asker is very new to programming, the "else" will make the function flow clearer.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems**

1. You are not using a recursive function
2. You are not calling your function ( you need to return the value of it then print it)
3. You are using 'n' as a input to your function call but then trying to overwrite it

**Solution**

Don't use recursion, it would be a bad use to recursively gather inputs from a user, also move the input call to outside of the function

```
def find_sum (n):
    sum_num = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
    return sum_num

n=int(input ("Enter a number: "))
result = str(find_sum(n))
print("The sum of first " + result)
```

Learn more about function calls [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Comment: You could simply return the equation

Answer (score 0):

You never acctually call your function

Try something like this:

```
def find_sum ():
    n=int(input ("Enter a number: "))
    sum_num = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
    return sum_num
sum = find_sum()
print("The sum of first"+sum)
```

this way the return value of `find_sum` will be saved to `sum`

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking input properly also you are not calling function also you have not used any concept of recursion.

Solution with recursion is below:

```py
def find_sum (n):
    if n==0:
      return 0
    else:
      return (n+sum(n-1))

n=int(input("Enter a number: "))

print("The sum of first"+find_sum(n))
```

If it solved your problem mark this as your answer

Comment: You are calling `sum_sum`, this will give an error.